# SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
try {  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://Localhost/basic_credit? autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false" ;

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,"root","superchan009");
    String sql="INSERT INTO new_table(date, time, customer_name, address, contact#1, contact#2, item_name, final_price, downpayment, remaining_balance, length_ofinstallment, payment_permonth, first_due, last_due)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);

    ps.setString(1,jLabel16.getText());
    ps.setString(2,jLabel17.getText());
    ps.setString(3,tf1.getText());
    ps.setString(4,tf2.getText());
    ps.setString(5,tf3.getText());
    ps.setString(6,tf4.getText());
    ps.setString(7,tf6.getText());
    ps.setString(8,tf7.getText());
    ps.setString(9,tf8.getText());
    ps.setString(10,tf9.getText());
    ps.setString(11,tf10.getText());
    ps.setString(12,tf11.getText());
    ps.setString(13,tf12.getText());
    ps.setString(14,tf13.getText());

    ps.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DATA SAVED! THANK YOU!");

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
    System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
}
```

Comment: A space is missing before `VALUES` .

Comment: Please help me with this one. I've already omitted the quotations in "?" but stil, it isn't working. What's wrong?

Comment: `contact#1` is unlikely to be a valid name without being escaped, what DB are you using?

Comment: @AlexK. : The URL suggests mySql .

Comment: Nothing happened after I've inserted a space before VALUES. Same error. SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: What should I do ?

Comment: replace `contact#1` with `\`contact#1\`` (same for `..#2`), you may need to do the same with `date` and `time`.

Comment: same error @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Please update your question with your current code.

Answer (score 2):

you are using `#` in column name is creating issue... you should remove `#` tag from column name and also correct it into database.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://Localhost/basic_credit? autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false" ;

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,"root","superchan009");
    String sql="INSERT INTO new_table(date, time, client_name, address, contact1, contact2, item_name, final_price, downpayment, remaining_balance, length_ofinstallment, payment_permonth, first_due, last_due) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);

    ps.setString(1,jLabel16.getText());
    ps.setString(2,jLabel17.getText());
    ps.setString(3,tf1.getText());
    ps.setString(4,tf2.getText());
    ps.setString(5,tf3.getText());
    ps.setString(6,tf4.getText());
    ps.setString(7,tf6.getText());
    ps.setString(8,tf7.getText());
    ps.setString(9,tf8.getText());
    ps.setString(10,tf9.getText());
    ps.setString(11,tf10.getText());
    ps.setString(12,tf11.getText());
    ps.setString(13,tf12.getText());
    ps.setString(14,tf13.getText());

    ps.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DATA SAVED! THANK YOU!");

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
    System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
}
```

SQL to JAVA connection is case sensitive if you're going to use special char "#" for column names.

Comment: Is this intended as an answer? If not, please **edit** your question instead; if it is an answer, then please add an explanation, not just code.